# Subject-Verb Agreement + Prepositional Phrase Argument

Tags: verb-agreement

Having an argument with my SO.

Participant 1 believes this is the correct way to structure the sentence:

> I'm learning how to do things in a way that serves me.

Participant 1 thinks that the verb, 'serve' should be 'serves' because 'way' modifies the verb and acts as the subject.

Participant 2 believes this is the correct way to structure the sentence:

> I'm learning how to do things in a way that serve me.

Participant 2 thinks 'serve' should remain 'serve' because the subject is 'things', and 'in a way' should be excluded when determining subject-verb agreement because it's a prepositional phrase. And if you exclude the prepositional phrase from the sentence, it reads 'I'm learning to do things that serve me.'

Which is the correct subject-verb agreement?

Comment: The subject is not _things_. The subject is _way_, which is singular. You can tell this because _that serves me_ is a relative clause, and they follow their antecedent, which refers to the relative pronoun. In this case, that relative pronoun is _that_, which is the subject of _that serves me_.

Comment: Yes @JohnLawler; agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm learning.  (*base*)
I'm learning how to do things. (*adjective phrase*)
I'm learning how to do things in a way. (*adjective phrase*)
I'm learning how to do things in a way that serves me.  (*adjective clause*)

"**a way that serves me.**" is the important part of the sentence.
"that" is a relative pronoun.
the antecedent for "that" is the adjacent noun, "a way".
"a way" is a singular noun.

*a way serves me.* // correct
*a way serve me.*

**NOTE**
If you want to try and say that "*that serves me*" modifies "**things**", then you would have:
I'm learning how to do things that **serve** me. // ok. "things" is plural. but wait...
I'm learning how to do things that serve me in a way. // grammatically correct. The antecedent for "that" is now plural, "things". But the dangling prepositional phrase, "in a way", does not make logical sense.